# Easiest way to do collision LWJGL JAVA

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl, collision

Ok so I have a ArrayList which contains all the tiles that need to be drawn to the screen and I have the player that is moved with the arrow keys, but I am unsure how I could implement collision detection with this, Would it be efficient to check if the current tile is filled and if so stop, This is my first time creating a game from scratch so any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The tiles are 32x32 images which are held in a ArrayList basically if you guys can help me with the y-axis collision i should be fine with the rest.
Tile class contains x, y, and the tile type

EDIT2:I havent tried anything yet, I don't really know where to start but basically i need some sort of Collision on tile, e.g While player is moving if collide on tile do something but i dont know how to check if i have collided or not

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue? What is holding the ArrayList on your panel? What exactly is the tile? Could you add some code to your issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: you want to know if the player(in location x,y) collides into a tile(of size 32*32).  The first thing you need to know is where the location of the tile is which is represented by the X, and Y in your tile class.  Then you can add 32 to both the X and Y values, to get the lower right corner of your image

Comment: Ok this is what i just tried but to no avail, what it does is it's meant to check before you move and if it passes you can move but its always passing :/ http://pastebin.com/BKS72b6y

Comment: your t.id is always equal to Title.TITLE_NORMAL.  and your return statement is testing for things, its not actually returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Below I have an example of a bouncing ball, which will test for the end of the JPanel, and do something

```
  //x = X-Axis Location //This tests for a collision of the JPanel on the left side or the right side
public boolean isLeavingSideToSide(JPanel jp)
{
    if( x <=0 || x+ width >= jp.getWidth())
    {
        BounceEvent be = new BounceEvent(this);
        notifyListeners(be);            
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

BounceEvent is created to allow for the notifyListener, which calls the bounced method.

```
public void notifyListeners(BounceEvent be)
{
    for(BounceListener bl : listeners)
    {
        bl.bounced(be);
    }
}
```

My Bounced method changes the color of the ball (Does some action)

```
public void bounced(BounceEvent be) {
    Ball b = be.getBall();
    Color c = b.getColor();
    int x = 256;
    int newColor1 = (int) (Math.random() * x);
    int newColor2 = (int) (Math.random() * x);
    int newColor3 = (int) (Math.random() * x);
    b.setColor(new Color(newColor1,newColor2,newColor3));
}
```

Hopefully this will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks but that only helps me with testing if the player has left the screen :/ I want to test to see if the Player has collided with a tile

Comment: That gives you a place to start your testing, if you can implement this for your screen, then you should understand how collisions work, and from there you will be able to ask a more specific question.  Remember, the more general your question, the less likely people will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection isn't matter for beginners, nor can it be fully explained in a Stackoverflow post; if you're still struggling with arrays, try to make simple games, where collision is detected by calculating the distance between objects like **circles**.

There are many ways to handle collision detection, but you have to be more specific:
**what kind of tile-based game are you planning to develop?**

I strongly suggest you to read [**this article**](http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/2d-platform-games-collision-detection-for-dummies/), by Katy Coe, which gives a summary of a few implementations. The following methods are explained in the aforementioned blog.

The simplest and most intuitive method is the **Pixel Colour Approach**, where players can move on tiles with a specific color value, but it can be used only with a limited color palette. The **Mask Approach** is essentially the same as PCA, but it hides black and white layers behind custom graphics; the latter is computationally expensive and not generally recommended.

The **Grid-Based Approach** is probably what you're looking for. Each element of the map corresponds to a tile of the grid (described by a 2D array). The player moves in a discrete space, although animation might fake fluid movements.

The **Pixel Tile Method** describes collisions by sorrounding characters with n control points; this approach let the developer use non-squared characters in a tiled world.
The **Bounding Box Method** is a simpler implementation of PTM, where the player is wrapped in a rectangle. The program checks whether any of the four corners of the rectangle intersect with any wall.

**Discrete Collision Detection**, or its improved version, **Speculative Contacts**, are used in more complex games and you surely don't need those now.

Don't try to learn all at once, **start with the simplest implementation you can think of**.
Otherwise, you would soon get discouraged and would not appreciate the pro/cons of each technique.

I've recently found [**this great tutorial**](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/tbw/start.html) about tile-based games with Macromedia Flash, but you can easily apply those techniques using your language of choice. **READ IT!**
If you want an alternative to Katy's articles, [**Rodrigo Monteiro comes in help**](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/).